# How to install MSSQL driver on Docker php-fpm image

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am trying to set up a Laravel development environment with Docker using docker-compose and Dockerfile for the php image. I need an MSSQL driver for php. All works fine except that I cannot install the MSSQL driver for php. Please help me find a solution. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
# COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/
 
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
 
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libwebp-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6 \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Install MSSQL driver
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install php7.3-sybase

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
 
# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
 
# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www
 
# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
 
# Change current user to www
USER www
 
# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

When building the php image I get the following error:

```
 > [ 6/13] RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install php7.3-sybase:                                                                                                
#9 0.410 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                      
#9 0.410 Hit:2 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease                                                                                                
#9 0.531 Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                       
#9 0.659 Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute Release                                                                                         
#9 0.659   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#9 0.671 Reading package lists...
#9 1.196 E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
```

In my understanding the php-fpm image is based on Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute, and and the php-sybase package has no release for 21.04. I tried to install a php image based on ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04 but I couldn't make it work. Php 7.2 or 7.3 would both work for me. Please help! Thank you.